# Network error (tcp_error) when uploading file using NeatUpload asp.net control

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking, neatupload

I get the error below when trying to upload files using NeatUpload asp.net control.

[image]

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error refers to a permission error for the folder in which you are uploading the file.

Kindly check the proper permission an it will work.